# What is the default pooling size of Max pooling layers in Keras?

Tags: python, keras

What is the default pooling size of maxpooling layers in Keras?
Pooling layers have 3 args: pool_size, strides and padding. If the pool_size is not explicitly specified, what pool_size value does Keras use by default?

For example in the following keras pooling layer, which is the pool_size?

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(strides=(2,2), padding='same'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default in Keras as it is in Tensorflow with the Keras backend is `pool_size=(2,2)`, therefore it will halve the input's `x` and `y` spatial dimensions.

[Here you can see the documentation in Tensorflow where it is mentioned.](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/MaxPool2D)

To be more specific, the `stride` and `pool_size` arguments are highly related and differ only when you change the padding type. As mentioned in the documentation:

`output_shape = math.floor((input_shape - pool_size) / strides) + 1` in the case where `input_shape >= pool_size` if the chosen padding is `valid`.

Otherwise, if chosen padding is `same`:

`output_shape = math.floor((input_shape - 1) / strides) + 1`